# HIVE: cannot recognize input near 'distinct' '('

Tags: hive

I am trying to execute the below query in Hive:

```
SELECT
  regexp_replace('2016-08-05_11:29:46', '\\_', ' ') as tmstmp,
  distinct(P.name)
FROM table P;
```

It throws an exception saying cannot recognize input near 'distinct' '(' 'P' in selection target.

where as when I run the query interchanging the columns like:

```
SELECT
  distinct(P.name),
  regexp_replace('2016-08-05_11:29:46', '\\_', ' ') as tmstmp
FROM table P;
```

It works fine. Any idea on the issue ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To my knowledge, This is a restriction imposed by hive in select syntax. 
As per the Select syntax in hive language manual , DISTINCT should come first in order followed by other expressions.

Reference:
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Select

I guess the reason being DISTINCT is a row level operation (even if its specified as function call for a column) and specifically in hive it will be a mapreduce operation.

The similar behavior could be observed in SQL ANSI standard supported database engines like Mysql as well.